# Windows 7 install locations

Tags: windows-7, installation

I had a win7 machine with two hard drives, an SSD to boot from and an HDD to store data.

The HDD died recently and I replaced it with another HDD. My problem is now when I try to install certain apps (notably Netbeans) it fails with the message `Cannot create local directory F:/nbi`

There's no `F:` drive-- the HDD is `D:`

Do I need to change a registry setting? Or should I remap `D:` to `F:`? I'm confused since the default app locations in the Windows registry are the normal `C:\Program Files` paths.